# failed to open stream and helper data not found in module

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am using `AdjustWare_Giftreg` module in magento 1.4 version. The page is not showing all the products.the module is `disabled` but it is still showing just one product. I also changed my hosting could be this the problem? with the compilation

Getting below error in the log:

```
- Warning: include(Mage/Adjgiftreg/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in..

- Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Adjgiftreg/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion
```

My files:

`app/etc/modules/AdjustWare_Giftreg.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
       <modules>
    <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <self_name>Gift Registry</self_name>
        <priority>70</priority>
    </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
</modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/AdjustWare/Giftreg/etc/config.xml`

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
          <config>
             <modules>
        <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <adjgiftreg>
                <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>adjgiftreg_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </adjgiftreg>
            <adjgiftreg_mysql4>
                <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <event>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_event</table>
                    </event>
                    <item>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <thank>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_thank</table>
                    </thank>
                    <order>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_order</table>
                    </order>
                    <type>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_type</table>
                    </type>
                    <type_title>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_type_title</table>
                    </type_title>
                    <item_option>
                        <table>adjgiftreg_item_option</table>
                    </item_option>
                </entities>
            </adjgiftreg_mysql4>

            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <type_onepage>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model_Rewrite_FrontCheckoutTypeOnepage</type_onepage>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>    
            <downloadable>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Model_Rewrite_DownloadableObserver</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </downloadable>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <adjgiftreg_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>AdjustWare_Giftreg</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </adjgiftreg_setup>
            <adjgiftreg_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </adjgiftreg_write>
            <adjgiftreg_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </adjgiftreg_read>
        </resources>
        <template>
            <email>
                <adjgiftreg_email_share translate="label" module="adjgiftreg">
                    <label>Gift Registry - Share </label>
                    <file>adjgiftreg_share.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </adjgiftreg_email_share>
                <adjgiftreg_email_notification translate="label" module="adjgiftreg">
                    <label>Gift Registry - System Notification</label>
                    <file>adjgiftreg_admin_notification.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </adjgiftreg_email_notification>
            </email>
        </template> 

        <blocks>
            <adjgiftreg>
                <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block</class>
            </adjgiftreg>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_edit_tabs>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block_Rewrite_AdminhtmlCustomerEditTabs</customer_edit_tabs>
                    <sales_order_view>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block_Rewrite_AdminhtmlView</sales_order_view>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Block_Rewrite_FrontCheckoutOnepageShipping</onepage_shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>


        <helpers>
            <adjgiftreg>
                <class>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper</class>
            </adjgiftreg>

            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>AdjustWare_Giftreg_Helper_Rewrite_CheckoutData</data>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </helpers>

        <events>
            <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>processCartAddProductComplete</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>

            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>processCartProductAdd</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>

            <sales_quote_remove_item>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>processCartProductRemoved</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_remove_item>

            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>processBeforeOrderSaved</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order>

            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>processAfterOrderSaved</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>

            <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>processCartUpdated</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
            <sales_quote_merge_before>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>mergeQuotes</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_merge_before>

            <aitoc_module_disable_before>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/moduleObserver</class>
                        <method>onAitocModuleDisableBefore</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </aitoc_module_disable_before> 

            <aitoc_editablecart_product_add>
                <observers>
                    <adjgiftreg>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>adjgiftreg/observer</class>
                        <method>onEditablecartProductAdd</method>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </observers>
            </aitoc_editablecart_product_add> 

        </events>
    </global>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <adjgiftreg_expire_event>
                <!-- each day-->
                <schedule><cron_expr>2 2 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>adjgiftreg/observer::expireEvents</model></run>
            </adjgiftreg_expire_event>

        </jobs> 
    </crontab> 


     <frontend>
        <routers>
            <adjgiftreg>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>AdjustWare_Giftreg</module>
                    <frontName>gifts</frontName>
                </args>
            </adjgiftreg>
        </routers>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
                    <files>
                        <default>AdjustWare_Giftreg.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
            </modules>
        </translate>
          <layout>
              <updates>
                  <adjgiftreg module="AdjustWare_Giftreg">
                      <file>adjgiftreg.xml</file>
                  </adjgiftreg>
              </updates>
          </layout>
    </frontend>   

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adjgiftregadmin>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>AdjustWare_Giftreg</module>
                    <frontName>adjgiftregadmin</frontName>
                </args>
            </adjgiftregadmin>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <customer>
                <children>
                    <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                        <title>Gift Registries</title>
                        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                <title>Registries</title>
                                <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_event</action>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </registries>
                            <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                <title>Event Types</title>
                                <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_type</action>
                                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            </types>
                        </children>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </children>
            </customer>
        </menu> 

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <customer>
                            <children>
                                <adjgiftreg translate="title">
                                    <title>Gift Registries</title>
                                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                    <children>
                                        <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                            <title>Registries</title>
                                        </registries>
                                        <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                            <title>Event Types</title>
                                        </types>
                                    </children>
                                </adjgiftreg>
                            </children>
                        </customer>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                                            <title>Gift Registries Section</title>
                                        </adjgiftreg>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system> 
                     </children>
                </admin> 
            </resources>
        </acl>

        <translate>
            <modules>
                <AdjustWare_Giftreg>
                    <files>
                        <default>AdjustWare_Giftreg.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </AdjustWare_Giftreg>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml> 

    <default>
        <adjgiftreg>
           <general>
                <active>0</active>
                <qty_warning>1</qty_warning>
                <secure>0</secure>
                <scope>0</scope>
            </general>
            <email>
                <share_identity>general</share_identity>
                <share>adjgiftreg_email_share</share>

                <notification_enable>1</notification_enable>
                <notification_identity>general</notification_identity>
                <notification>adjgiftreg_email_notification</notification>
                <notification_recipient><![CDATA[admin@example.com]]></notification_recipient>
            </email> 
        </adjgiftreg>
    </default>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/AdjustWare/Giftreg/etc/adminhtml.xml`

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <config>
            <menu>
            <customer>
                <children>
                    <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                        <title>Gift Registries</title>
                        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                <title>Registries</title>
                                <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_event</action>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </registries>
                            <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                <title>Event Types</title>
                                <action>adjgiftregadmin/adminhtml_type</action>
                                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            </types>
                        </children>
                    </adjgiftreg>
                </children>
            </customer>
        </menu> 

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <customer>
                            <children>
                                <adjgiftreg translate="title">
                                    <title>Gift Registries</title>
                                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                    <children>
                                        <registries translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                            <title>Registries</title>
                                        </registries>
                                        <types translate="title" module="adjgiftreg"> 
                                            <title>Event Types</title>
                                        </types>
                                    </children>
                                </adjgiftreg>
                            </children>
                        </customer>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <adjgiftreg translate="title" module="adjgiftreg">
                                            <title>Gift Registries Section</title>
                                        </adjgiftreg>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system> 
                     </children>
                </admin> 
            </resources>
        </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Do you have a Data helper in your module? I.e. `app/code/local/AdjustWare/Giftreg/Helper/Data.php`

Comment: Yes i have that file @RobbieAverill